# Git pull create a new branch every time

Tags: git

So I have a strange bug with git.

Every time and wherever I launch a `git pull` I'm ending up with a new branch created.

`* [new branch]      Lazy-loading -> origin/Lazy-loading`

However this branch is since a long time merge on the master and has not been updated since ages.

Could it be due to some cache problem somewhere? How can I clean this?

Comment: Your question reads a little misleading, hence the answer you got. You want to know why this happens and how to prevent it from happening again, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you do `git pull`, git fetches all branches that exist remotely and updates remote references for them.

```
* ef84e7e..6ee10e3  master     -> origin/master
* [new branch]      Lazy-loading -> origin/Lazy-loading
```

`[new branch]` means that there was branch called `Lazy-loading` in remote repository, but not in your local repository.

You should delete that branch remotely first with `git push origin --delete Lazy-loading` or `git push origin :Lazy-loading` to stop this happening.

Then you could do this:

```
git fetch --prune
```

This will fetch from remote repository again and delete all local branches which track branches that no longer exist on the remote.

> *--prune*
>
> Before fetching, remove any remote-tracking references that no longer exist on the remote. Tags are not subject to pruning if they
> are fetched only because of the default tag auto-following or due to a
> --tags option. However, if tags are fetched due to an explicit refspec (either on the command line or in the remote configuration, for
> example if the remote was cloned with the --mirror option), then they
> are also subject to pruning.

Answer (score -1):

If you are not going to use the branch at all, you can delete it both locally and remotely:

To delete the local branch:

```
git branch -d Lazy-loading
```

Then delete it remotely:

```
git push origin --delete Lazy-loading
```